# How to insert divs correctly to manipulate them from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i have some code to create div with specified class, and inside of this div i create iframe to connect to my chat widget

```
(function(){ 
var client_id = '1',
    p= 'right',
    vp = 'bottom';
    h = '550',
    dw = '400';
var d=document;
var w=window;

function l(){

    var s = document.createElement('div');
    s.id = 'chatrix_init_widget'; 
    s.style = 'position: fixed; z-index:101010; '+p+': 0; '+vp+': 0; height:'+h+'px; width: '+dw+'px';
    var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);

    var i = document.createElement('iframe');
    i.className = 'chatrix_iframe_container';
    i.height = '100%';
    i.width = '100%';
    i.src = '//danialart.biz/chatrix/widget.php?c='+client_id;
    var ss = document.getElementById('chatrix_init_widget').appendChild(i);

}
function s() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    s.src = '//danialart.biz/chatrix/js/client_side.js';
    var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
}

if(d.readyState=='complete'){
    l();
    s();
}else{
    if(w.attachEvent){
        w.attachEvent('onload',l);
        s();
}else{
    w.addEventListener('load',l,false); s();}}})();
```

In function named s() i create script tag which connect remote jquery file functions, but nothing in this file (execlude consolel.log command) is work. Not click, or other jquery action not work at all.

Comment: Duplicate or related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: @DanialartBiz I have replicated your condition and i made it work. Please check the updated solution if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Its often this problem when `iframes` are involved. I suggest three ways to go:

1. Try `onload` on the element on which you are trying to put jquery action:

   ```
   $('#element').on('load',function(){
      //your action here for example click action
      $(this).on('click',function(){
      });
   });
   ```
2. Try `onload` on your iframe:

   ```
   $('.chatrix_iframe_container').on('load', function(){
      //do your actions here
   });
   ```

Although sometimes none of above works then I use `setInterval` which I don't suggest normally as its considered bad practice

3. Use `setInterval`

   ```
    function myAction(){
       if($('#element').length){
         // do your actions here
         clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
    var timer = setInterval(function(){myAction();},1000);
   ```

I have made test myself and I could get your logic to work by doing following modifications:

1. Add jQuery in your `<head>` tag:

   `<head>`
     `<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

   `</head>`
2. Replace your starting of script:

   ```
   (function(){
   ```

with this:

```
(function($){
```

3.In the end of your script, use this:

```
if(d.readyState=='complete'){
    l();
    s();
}else{
    if(w.attachEvent){
        w.attachEvent('onload',function(){
          l();
          s();
        });
}else{
    w.addEventListener('load',function(){l();s();},false);}}})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I have replicated your situation and now it worked like this as I have found out that `w.addEventListener` is the one who is loading your script and it was adding the script tag(`s()`) even before `div` was being added to DOM(`l()`). That is why script wasn't working.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I tried all the three solutions, but not one is work, as before - i clicked all over the element but nothing happend. I gues its promblem of insertion div and iframe, if i insert it directly (not in javascript) - my jquery code work fine, but if i create when DOM is load - its not.

Comment: problem is that your jquery code is trying to target the element when its not present in DOM so you need to wait for it to be added and then target it. Now i don't know why none of above solutions worked. In solution 3, remove the line : `clearInterval(timer);` and try again. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Nope, still nothing change. Can u, maybe, tell me how to create elements in DOM in way which jquery is will be working. My target is -  to create small js code which every users can paste to they websites and which create iframe, div and sonnect jquery js file from another sever to manipulated of creating elements?

Comment: The only fact you need to take care of is that you only try to do manipulations on dynamically added elements after they are added to DOM. that means any jquery to try to execute when element isnt in the DOM would not work.

Comment: Seeing your question, I would like you to try one more thing to see if it works. In your code all actions you want to take, put them after you call `l()` that means you need to make a function including all your actions and call that function after you call `l()`.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if that works. Please reply what happens.

Comment: i create function called s, and inside that function i create new DOM element script with link to jquery script what i need, and call function s() (which connect file after create div in dom) but anyway clicking on my div not working. But when i call console.log($('.chatrix_init_widget')); - i see my element in console. But click still not working.

Comment: Can you update question with this latest function you have created ? So that i can get a clear idea of why it isnt working.

Comment: @DanialartBiz I have replicated your condition and i made it work. Please check the updated solution and tell me if it works for you.